# Nginx статика отдача

Tags: nginx

Пытаюсь настроить Nginx.
Установил из пакетов по умолчанию.
Удалил файл default из sites-available и sites-enabled.

nginx.config

```
events {}
http {

  server {
         server_name 192.168.111.111;
         root root/path/to/static/;
         }
}
```

Однако, при обращении по адресу, nginx отдаёт 404, т.к ищет html файл не в папке root, а перед ней добавляет /usr/share/nginx/и уже добавляет тут root/path/to/static.

Как убрать этот чертов префикс /usr/share/nginx?

Comment: Напишите абсолютный путь вместо относительного, и ничего добавляться не будет

Comment: Он и так абсолютный прописан

Comment: В том конфиге, который вы здесь показали, прописан относительный адрес

Comment: Вы верно написали! Теперь ругается 403, но это я так понимаю уже права какие-то доступа?

Comment: Да. . . . . . .